# Is mass of solute included in calculation of enthalpy of solution?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, solutions, heat

> $$
> \begin{array}{lrrrr}
> \hline
>   & \ce{MgSO4} & \ce{K2SO4} & \ce{KNO3} & \ce{NH4NO3} \\
> \hline
> m/\pu{g} & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 \\
> M/\pu{g mol^-1} & 120.37 & 174.26 & 101.10 & 80.04 \\
> n/\pu{mmol} & 124 & 90 & 148 & 187 \\
> T_0/\pu{°C} & 28.0 & 28.0 & 28.0 & 28.0 \\
> T_1/\pu{°C} & 74.1 & 22.3 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

To solve for the heat of solution of $\ce{MgSO4}$ we use the formula

$$q = -mc\,ΔT \tag{1}$$

What should be the value for mass $m$ given the data?
Should I add the mass of water $(\pu{30 g})$ *and* the mass of salt $(\pu{15 g}),$ or should it *just* be water?

$$
\begin{align}
q(\ce{MgSO4}) &= -(\pu{45 g})(\pu{4.184 J g^-1 °C^-1})(\pu{74.1 °C} - \pu{28.0 °C}) \\
  &= \pu{-8.68 kJ} \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\Delta_\mathrm{soln}H(\ce{MgSO4}) &= \frac{q(\ce{MgSO4})}{n(\ce{MgSO4})} \\
  &= \frac{\pu{-8.68 kJ}}{\pu{124 mmol}} \\
  & \approx \pu{70 kJ mol^-1} \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I don't we can ignore the the fact the percentage of salt is too high, you are adding 15 g of the salt to 30 mL of water. That is a lot! In this case, the heat capacity of the *solution* should be used not that of water and then total mass should be used. I don't know who makes up these questions in the textbooks/tests without thinking.

Comment: @AChem when you said total mass, you meant to add the molar mass of the 2 substances? MG and SO4?

Comment: @Red, I think it should be mass of magnesium sulfate in grams that you have added to the mass of water. The key issue is that you do not have specific heat capacity of that solution which is 50% MgSO4 by mass. It is a badly designed question.

Comment: @AChem Confused right now since my friend used 34.972 as m in the formula. I was wondering how he got it

Comment: @Red, Your calculations appear to be correct. Ignore your friend's random numbers. The only issue I see is that this is 50% by wt MgSO4, so water's heat capacity is an approximation.

Comment: @AChem, in other words i'll use 120.37 instead of 45?

Comment: I do not know how and where you are generating random numbers such as 120.37,  45, 33.972, that too without unit!  *Your solution looks okay, as it is.* Do you understand what is being done in the table and in the solution? When you solved it correctly, why are you still so confused?

Comment: @AChem, just so i would understand this what would be your value in m in the case of potassium sulfate?